# Is it possible way to load and execute external script, without blocking main thead without using web workers (js)

Tags: javascript

I want to optimize my site. When I even try to load some scripts after the page has page loaded it will block the main thread. Dev tools' *audit* will show much better results, but it will still block the main thread.

I've found a method by which code can be executed without blocking: Web Workers, but then you don't have access to the `window` object which is a problem because you can only execute some scripts which don't use it.

Is there any available method load and execute an external script without blocking the main thread?

Here is my code:

```
         import useScriptLoader from "@andreyradkevichasap/use-script-loader-hook";

         const { load } = useScriptLoader()

         Promise.all([
            load({
              src:
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'
            }),
            load({
              src: 'https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js'
            })
          ]).then(() => {
            const script = document.createElement('script')
            script.type = 'text/javascript'
            script.async = true
            script.innerHTML = 'some script'
            document.body.appendChild(script)
           })
```

Comment: Script loading does not block the main thread,  script execution on the other hand might.  Have you looked at the `defer` & `async` attribute of the script tag to see if that will help.?  https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Comment: I've attached the code by which I try to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Running code in asynchronously will not block the main thread.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Marking a function `async` makes it return a promise. It doesn't stop blocking code from blocking. There is still only one event loop.

Comment: You could try splitting up the code into smaller separate parts which are executed one after each other. Starting the next part when the first promise has returned. Giving the main thread time to update the UI in between the promises, which would make it feel like nothing is blocked.

Answer (score -1):

You might use a setTimeout to put the external script execution into the event loop's queue. Then it won't block the main thread and it will be executed at the end.